# Increment 3rd occurence of digit in string with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

`[group][100][250][3][person]`

and I need to increment the number `3`. I tried the regex `/\[\d+\]/` which matches all 3, but I couldn't get anywhere from here.

Comment: is the string always formatted in this way - AKA do you know in advance the position of the 3?

Comment: Yes. It will always be in that format, although the numbers `100` and `250` could be `123456` and `654321` for example. They could be any length.

Comment: Your question is unclear since you don't explain why you want `[3]` and not `[100]` or `[250]`. Reading your previous question I suspect that you choose this one for its position, however you don't say if you want the last or the third.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Replace nth occurrence of string](//stackoverflow.com/q/35499498)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Title clearly says "3rd"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by matching all 3 of your numeric values and just increment the third:

```js
var regex = /\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]/g

var input = "[group][100][250][3][person]";

var result = input.replace(regex, function(match,p1,p2,p3){
  return "[" + p1 + "][" + p2 + "][" + (parseInt(p3,10) + 1) + "]"
})
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace` with a callback function:

```js
var s = "[group][100][250][3][person]";
var repl = s.replace(/((?:\[\d+\]){2}\[)(\d+)\]/,
          function($0, $1, $2) { return $1 + (parseInt($2)+1) + ']'; }
);

console.log(repl);
//=> "[group][100][250][4][person]"
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture "your" string, try the below regex:

```
(?:\[\d+\]){2}\[(\d+)\]
```

How it works:

- `(?:...){2}` - a non-capturing group, occuring 2 times.
- `\[\d+\]` - containing `[`, a sequence of digits and `]`.
- `[`, a capturing group - sequence of digits and `]`.

The text you want to capture is in the first capturing proup.